# Round method in a fraction class

Tags: python

I've been building a fraction class and I've one method that is not functioning properly. 
I'm not totally sure how this function is supposed to work and I need help understanding it. At the bottom of the code I have a test of each of the functions and with the provided information I was wondering if someone could give me insight on how to fix my method so that the class will function properly.

```
import math
#This class will be able to create fraction objects and will allow you do to regular perform regular math on it such as divsion, subtraction, multiplication, division,
#And things such as power
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self,numerator=0,denominator=1):
        '''
        Initializes the Fraction to the numerator and denominator
        values provided by the constructor.

        numerator - value of numerator with a default value of 0.
                    The type must be of integer.
        denomenator - value of denomenator with a default value of 1.
                      The type must be of integer.
        '''
        if not isinstance(denominator,int):
            raise TypeError("denominator must be of type int!")
        if not isinstance(numerator,int):
            raise TypeError("numerator must be of type int!")
        if denominator == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError("Denominator cannot be 0")
        self.numer = numerator
        self.denom = denominator
        self.normalize()

    def __str__(self):
        s = "%d /% d" % (self.numer,self.denom)
        return s

    def normalize(self):
        reduce = Fraction.gcd(self.numer, self.denom)
        self.numer = self.numer // reduce
        self.denom = self.denom // reduce

    #When testing the GCD of a certain fraction create a new one like (x = Fraction) with no parameters. Then invoke the method with (x.gcd(a,b))..
    #This will find the greatest common denominator 
    def gcd(a,b):
        while b:
            a, b = b, a%b
        return a

    # necessary to define so that it is usable on hashable
    # collections like set, dict, etc..
    def __hash__(self):
        '''' returns the hash of the fraction equivalent to
        the hash of the floating point number the fraction represents.
        '''
        return hash(self.numer/self.denom) # use hash of floating point equiv.

    # comparison operators

    def __lt__(self,other):
        ''' returns True if this fraction is less than the other
        fraction, false otherwise.
        '''
        if isinstance(other,int):
            other = Fraction(other, self.denom)
            return self.numer*other.denom < other.numer*self.denom
        elif isinstance(other,float):
            return float(self) < other
        return self.numer*other.denom < other.numer*self.denom
    #Returns true if fracrion is less or equal to other fraction and false otherwise
    def __le__(self,other):
        ''' returns True if this fraction is less than or equal
        to the other fraction, false otherwise.
        '''
        if isinstance(other,int):
            other = Fraction(other, self.denom)
            return self.numer*other.denom <= other.numer*self.denom
        elif isinstance(other,float):
            return float(self) <= other
        return self.numer*other.denom <= other.numer*self.denom
    #Tests if one fraction is equal to the other
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other,Fraction):
            return int(self) == other
        return self.numer*other.denom == other.numer*self.denom
    #Tests if on fraction is not equal to the other
    def __ne__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other,Fraction):
            return int(self) != other
        return self.numer*other.denom != other.numer*self.denom
    #Return true if fraction is greater than other fraction.. If not it will return false
    def __gt__(self, other):

        if not isinstance(other,Fraction):
            other = int(other)
            other = Fraction(other, self.denom)
            return self.numer*other.denom > other.numer*self.denom 
        return self.numer*other.denom > other.numer*self.denom 
    #Returns true if the fraction is less than or equal to fraction and false if it is not
    def __ge__(self, other):
         if not isinstance(other,Fraction):
             other = int(other)
             other = Fraction(other, self.denom)
             return self.numer*other.denom >= other.numer*self.denom
         return self.numer*other.denom >= other.numer*self.denom

    #Arithmetic operators
        #this is the addition operator
    def __add__(self, other):
        ''' returns an instance of a Fraction that represents the sum
        of the fraction reprsented by self and other.
        '''
        if isinstance(other,int):
             return Fraction(self.numer + other*self.denom, self.denom)
        elif isinstance(other,float):
             return Fraction(self.numer + int(other)*self.denom, self.denom)
        elif isinstance(other,Fraction):
             return Fraction(self.numer*other.denom+other.numer*self.denom, self.denom*other.denom)
        else:
            return NotImplemented
    #Multiplication and division operators
    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other,int):
            return Fraction(self.numer-other*self.denom, self.denom)
        elif isinstance(other,float):
            return Fraction(int(self.numer-other*self.denom), self.denom)
        elif isinstance(other,Fraction):
           return Fraction(other.denom*self.numer-self.denom*other.numer, self.denom*other.denom)
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    #Multiplication operator
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return Fraction(self.numer*other, self.denom)
        elif isinstance(other, float):
            return Fraction(int(self.numer*other), self.denom)
        elif isinstance(other, Fraction):
            return Fraction(self.numer*other.numer, self.denom*other.denom)

        else:
            return NotImplemented
    #Division operator
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return Fraction(self.numer, self.denom*other)
        elif isinstance(other, float):
            return Fraction(int(self.numer), int(self.denom*other))
        elif isinstance(other, Fraction):
            return Fraction(self.numer*other.denom, self.denom*other.numer)

        else:
            return NotImplemented
    #This is the power operator... It will raise both numer and denom to the power
    def __pow__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return Fraction(self.numer ** other, self.denom ** other)
        elif isinstance(other, float):
            return Fraction(int(self.numer ** other), int(self.denom ** other))
        elif isinstance(other, Fraction):
            return Fraction(self.numer ** int(other.numer/other.denom), self.denom ** int(other.numer/other.denom))



    # reflected swapped operands
    def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other,int):
            return Fraction(self.numer + other *self.denom, self.denom)
        elif isinstance(other,float):
            return Fraction(self.numer + int(other)*self.denom, self.denom)
        return self + Fraction(other,1)
    #These methods are called if their counterparts don't exist
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other,int):
            return Fraction(other*self.denom-self.numer , self.denom)
        elif isinstance(other,float):
            return Fraction(int(other*self.denom-self.numer), self.denom)
        elif isinstance(other,Fraction):
           return  Fraction(other,1)- self
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return Fraction(self.numer*other, self.denom)
        elif isinstance(other, float):
            return Fraction(int(self.numer*other), self.denom)
        return self * Fraction(other,1)

    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other,int):
            return Fraction(self.denom*other, self.numer)
        elif isinstance(other, float):
            return Fraction(int(self.denom*other), self.numer)
        return self / Fraction(other,1)

    def __rpow__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return Fraction(int(other ** (self.numer/self.denom)), int(other ** (self.numer/self.denom)))
        elif isinstance(other, float):
            return Fraction(int(other ** (self.numer/self.denom)), int(other ** (self.numer/self.denom)))
        elif isinstance(other, Fraction):
            return Fraction(self.numer ** int(other.numer/other.denom), self.denom ** int(other.numer/other.denom))
        return self ** Fraction(other,1)

    # augmented operators

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        ''' returns an instance of a Fraction that represents the sum
        of the fraction reprsented by self and other.  This new instance
        becomes the new self.
        '''
        # Use the fact that the __add__ method
        # takes care of all all cases.
        #
        # return the new Fraction object.  This becomes
        # the new self!
        return self + other
    #This is the augment for subtraction
    def __isub__(self, other):
        return self - other
    #This is the augment for multiplication
    def __imul__(self, other):
        return self * other
    #This is the augment for Division
    def __itruediv__(self, other):
        return self / other
    #All of these methods below are COMPLETE
    # unary operators and absolute value
     #This will cause the fraction to be negative
    def __neg__(self):
        return Fraction(-self.numer, self.denom)

    #This will cause the fractions to be positive
    def __pos__(self):
        return Fraction(+self.numer, self.denom)
    #This will calculate the absolute value of the fraction
    def __abs__(self):
        return Fraction(abs(self.numer),abs(self.denom))

    # converting and rounding off
    #This will turn the fraction into an integer
    def __int__(self):
        value = self.numer/self.denom
        value = math.floor(value)
        return value

    #This will turn the fraction into a float type
    def __float__(self):
        floatValue = self.numer/self.denom
        return floatValue 
    #This will round the fraction down to a single int with the ceiling function
    def __round__(self, n=0):
        n = self.numer/self.denom
        n = math.ceil(n)
        return n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import copy
    a = Fraction(8,32)
    assert a == Fraction(1,4)
    b = Fraction(2,-16)
    assert b == Fraction(-1,8)
    # comparison operators
    assert (a < b) == False
    assert b < a
    assert(a < 0) == False
    assert a < 2
    assert a < 2.0

    assert (a <= b) == False
    assert b <= a
    assert a <= a
    assert (a <= 0) == False
    assert a <= 2
    assert a <= 2.0

    assert a > b
    assert (b > a) == False
    assert a > 0
    assert (a > 2) == False
    assert (a > 2.0) == False

    assert a >= b
    assert (b >= a) == False
    assert a >= a
    assert a >= 0
    assert (a >= 2) == False
    assert (a >= 2.0) == False

    assert (a == b) == False
    assert b == b
    assert a == a
    assert a != b
    assert (b != b) == False
    # addition
    assert a+2 == Fraction(9,4)
    assert 2+a == Fraction(9,4)
    assert a > 0.0001
    assert abs((a+2.0)-(9/4)) < 0.0001
    assert abs((2.0+a)-(9/4)) < 0.0001
    assert a+b == Fraction(1,8)
    assert a+Fraction(1,3) == Fraction(7,12)
    # subtraction
    assert a-2 == Fraction(-7,4)
    assert 2-a == Fraction(7,4)
    assert abs((a-2.0)-(-7/4)) < 0.0001
    assert abs((2.0-a)-(7/4)) < 0.0001
    assert a-b == Fraction(3,8)
    assert b-a == Fraction(-3,8)
    assert a-Fraction(1,3) == Fraction(-1,12)
    # multiplication
    assert a*2 == Fraction(1,2)
    assert 2*a == Fraction(1,2)
    assert abs((a*2.0)-(1/2)) < 0.0001
    assert abs((2.0*a)-(1/2)) < 0.0001
    assert a*b == Fraction(-1,32)
    # division
    assert a/2 == Fraction(1,8)
    assert 2/a == Fraction(8,1)
    assert abs((a/2.0)-(1/8)) < 0.0001
    assert abs((2.0/a)-8.0) < 0.0001
    assert abs(a/b - (-2.0)) < 0.0001
    # power
    assert a**2 == Fraction(1,16)
    assert abs(2**a - 2**(1/4)) < 0.0001
    assert abs((a**2.0)-(1/4)**2.0) < 0.0001
    assert abs((2.0**a)-2.0**(1/4)) < 0.0001
    assert abs(a**b - (1/4)**(-1/8)) < 0.0001
    # += operator
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c += 2
    assert c == Fraction(9,4)
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c += 2.0
    assert abs(c -(9/4)) < 0.0001
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c += b
    assert c == Fraction(1,8)
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c += Fraction(1,3)
    assert c == Fraction(7,12)
    # -= operator
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c -= 2
    assert c == Fraction(-7,4)
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c -= 2.0
    assert abs((c)-(-7/4)) < 0.0001
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c -= b
    assert c == Fraction(3,8)
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c -= Fraction(1,3)
    assert c == Fraction(-1,12)

    # *= operator
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c *= 2
    assert c == Fraction(1,2)
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c *= 2.0
    assert abs((a*2.0)-(1/2)) < 0.0001
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c *= b
    assert c == Fraction(-1,32)

    # /= operator
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c /= 2
    assert c == Fraction(1,8)
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c /= 2.0
    assert abs(c -(1/8)) < 0.0001
    c = copy.copy(a)
    c /= b
    assert abs(c - (-2.0)) < 0.0001

    # -a, +a , |a|
    assert -a == Fraction(-1,4)
    assert -b == Fraction(1,8)
    assert +a == a
    assert abs(b) == Fraction(1,8)

    # int, float, round

    assert int(Fraction(4,3)) == 1
    assert int(Fraction(3,4)) == 0
    #Could not get these to work.
    assert abs(float(a)-(1/4)) < 0.0001 
    assert abs(float(b)-(-1/8)) < 0.0001
    assert abs(round(b,2)- (-.12)) < 0.0001
    assert abs(round(b,1)- (-.1)) < 0.0001
```

Comment: Sorry for the code looking all funky. I'm unsure on how to format it properly when posted here

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What exactly isn't operating correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your definition of your `round` function. Presumably you need:

```
#This will round the fraction down to a single int with the ceiling function
def __round__(self, n=0):
    return round(self.numer/self.denom, n)
```

instead of

```
def __round__(self, n=0):
    n = self.numer/self.denom
    n = math.ceil(n)
    return n
```

which doesn't make much sense in the context your using it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you give me an example of how I should explain a problem next time? I'm not used to doing this

Comment: Sure: basically, post the smallest bit of code that demonstrates your problem (so leave out all the `assert` statements that work, and your class methods which are also working). Then (if you haven't worked out the problem by doing this, which sometimes happens), be sure to post the results which summarize your problem: what happens _and_ what you want to happen.